# How to use openssh

Tags: windows, centos, openssh

I have two servers, A and B.

A is a Windows 2003 server and B is a CentOS 7 server.

I installed openssh for windows on A, but I don't know how to set B's ssh_config so that I can connect to B from A with RSA keys.

**Eidt 2015-08-05 23:18:34**

Sorry about my confusing question.

1. I can only use command not a client.
2. I have to connect to B from A with RSA keys.
3. I have generated key and upload pub to B.
4. I have tried ssh user@b.ip but not usefull.

Comment: -1  define server 'cos you're saying you have 2 servers A and B, connecting one to the other,  that's not clear re server. So what do you mean server , do you mean big powerful computersl.. I don't care how big and powerful the computers are, that's not relevant.   And you contradict yourself, you talk of setting B's ssh_config so B is the client, then you talk of connecting from A, which would be A to B.

Comment: And by the way, it isn't necessary to configure ssh_config

Comment: Its very clear he wants to connect from the Windows 2003 Server, called A, to the CentOS 7 server, called B!

Comment: @Josef fine,,,your intrepretation makes sense. I'd note that it's called Windows Server 2003.

Comment: @Josef yeah ,you are right.

Comment: I have to use command instead of client software.

Comment: @WhiteWater can you log in via user/pass?

Comment: @barlop Yes, I can log in via user/pass, but not useful with RSA keys.

Comment: First of all you have contradicted yourself AGAIN    Josef said you are connecting from A to B. You said he is correct.   You wrote " I don't know how to set B's ssh_config so that I can connect to B from A with RSA keys."   Now you write "I have to connect to A from B with RSA keys"

Comment: Try to get right, how to say FROM A TO B and get the direction right.  That means you start from A, and thne you go to B. Now just state which is A, and which is B

Comment: = =.. I'm sure about starting from A then to B. I write mistake .sorry. @barlop

Comment: I have updated my question. @barlop

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26626/discussion-between-barlop-and-whitewater).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you can login via user/pass

you just need to generate a key and copy it over

try running ssh-keygen where your ssh client is, to generate a key, it will make id_rsa and id_rsa.pub in your home directory where your ssh client is.

ssh-copy-id user@host    to copy the key to the ssh server. You will be prompted to login with a user/pass and then the key will have been copied over and you can log in automatically via key.  It will append your public key to authorized_keys file on the ssh server

Your ssh_config file and sshd_config file shouldn't need any amended to do that.

Comment: I have updated my question.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to set anything special for a Windows client, usually. The defaults in CentOS where your ssh server is, work fine.
If you have problems with openssh, use [PuTTY](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html) or [KiTTY](http://www.9bis.net/kitty/) as your windows ssh client, they are easier to grasp for the GUI-type of users.

Do you have problems setting up key authentication, or what exactly is the problem?
Try using username/password first and change to public key authentication once that works. (And **disable** password authentication on the server, if it is publicly reachable)

For public-key authentication you have to create a key pair at your client (A) using puttygen or ssh-keygen, and then add the public key (looks like *ssh-rsa BASE64...THINGY== comment*) into the file ~/.ssh/authorized_keys on the server (B). ~ here is the home directory of the user you use to login, so e.g. /home/user/.ssh/authorized_keys

Comment: But unfortunately, if I set default in centos, I can't connect without password. Actually, I have to input password.

Comment: -1 You wrote " If you have problems with openssh, use PuTTY " <--- putty is not a server, only a client

Comment: @WhiteWater Of course, you have to add the client certificate on the server! https://www.howtoforge.com/ssh_key_based_logins_putty

Comment: -1 @barlop I suggested to use the PuTTY client to connect to the OpenSSH server on CentOS instead of openssh for windows!

Comment: -1 @barlop I have to use by cmd instead of client. I have update my question.

Comment: fine, I think your interpretation of his setup is correct/good,  I removed the downvote and made it clearer what his setup is